# Angular fails to find interface import

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have an interface:

```
export interface MyInterface {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

With an index.ts file in the same folder:

```
export * from './my-interface';
```

And a component where I'm using the interface (details removed, models is the folder the index and interface sit in):

```
...
import { MyInterface } from 'src/app/common/models';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
}
```

The component works normally and there are no issues. I wanted to start creating my own type interfaces but I keep getting this error, pointing at my component file:

**Cannot find module 'src/app/common/models'.**

Note: this is the path to where the index file and interface sit.

I'm not quite sure what this error wants from me.
The component is correctly imported in app.modules so I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Add the actual name of the module to the end of the import statement, i.e., " import { MyInterface } from 'src/app/common/models/my-interface'; "

Comment: People, this is called a "barrel". Please don't tell him to import the interface directly as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Cannot find module 'src/app/common/models'

Means that the TypeScript compiler can not resolve the path to the `index.ts` file.

Try using a *relative* path instead.

```
import { MyInterface } from '../../app/common/models';
```

Where the number of `../` depends upon the location of the folder.

Also, make sure you restart `ng serve --watch` when adding barrels to a project. I've found that TypeScript caching will sometimes not pick up the change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the helpful advice! It auto imported the path for me so I didn't even think to question it much.

Answer (score -1):

Is "models" a directory? Because you should import a ts file. In your case might be

import { MyInterface } from 'src/app/common/models/my-interface'